# How can I show only min and max data labels in chartjs 3.3.2?

Tags: chart.js

I want to display only min an max data label in chartjs 3.3.2.
This work is not related with yticks. I want to show min and max data labels in chart.
How can I make it with chartjs-plugin-datalabel?

I think that can make with datalabels formatter.